# Upload file (size <16MB) to MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, file, file-upload

I have a requirement to upload file to MongoDB. Currently I am saving files in a folder in current filesystem using Flask. Is there a way I can upload file to MongoDB without using GridFS? I believe I did something like this long before but I cannot recollect since its been longtime since I last used MongoDB.

Any file I select to upload is no more than 16MB in size.

Update: I tried this to convert image file using `binData` but it throws error `global name binData is not defined`.

```
import pymongo
import base64
import bson

# establish a connection to the database
connection = pymongo.MongoClient()

#get a handle to the test database
db = connection.test
file_meta = db.file_meta
file_used = "Headshot.jpg"

def main():
    coll = db.sample
    with open(file_used, "r") as fin:
        f = fin.read()
        encoded = binData(f)

    coll.insert({"filename": file_used, "file": f, "description": "test" })
```

Comment: Have you tried saving it as a blob to the document?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mongo BSON (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/) has binary data (`binData`) type for  field.
Python driver (http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/binary.html) supports it.

You  can store file as array of bytes.

You code should be slightly modified:

1. Add import: `from bson.binary import Binary`
2. Encode file bytes using Binary: `encoded = Binary(f)`
3. Use encoded value in insert statement.

Full example below:

```
import pymongo
import base64
import bson
from bson.binary import Binary

# establish a connection to the database
connection = pymongo.MongoClient()

#get a handle to the test database
db = connection.test
file_meta = db.file_meta
file_used = "Headshot.jpg"

def main():
    coll = db.sample
    with open(file_used, "rb") as f:
        encoded = Binary(f.read())

    coll.insert({"filename": file_used, "file": encoded, "description": "test" })
```

Comment: I'm not able to upload files using binData type. Not sure if I am on right track converting file to using binData. Could you please let me know what is wrong with this code.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mike. It worked like a charm. One small correction though. I had to open the file in "rb" mode.