# upload a file with FastAPI and save to MongoDB bson

Tags: mongodb, file, fastapi, bson

I would like to upload files (mainly pdf and images, max 16MB) with FastAPI and save it directly in a MongoDB collection in a binary format (bson).

I know how to upload a file with FastAPI and save it in the file system. I know how to load a file from the file system and save it into a MongoDB collection. But my goal is to save the uploaded files directly into MongoDB, without passing through the file system, and the problem is how to code/decode the FastAPI UploadFile object into a MongoDB BinData (bson) format.

Anybody knows how to do it, showing with an example code?

Comment: UploadFile has a `file` attribute which is a spooled temporary file - this is a file-like interface, so you can just use it directly as you'd use any file in your Mongo-client: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile

Comment: Thanks, do you have a full code example to see how to load a file with MongoClient? Because I can load a file using mongo shell with fs.readFileSync, but I don't know how to load it with PyMongo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015103/upload-file-size-16mb-to-mongodb ?

Comment: In addition to Mats's comment on FastAPI/Starlette's `UploadFile`, you might find the following answers helpful: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71886990/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70653605/17865804)